# Laravel extend Eloquent when creating model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When creating a basic model in Laravel, I extend the `Eloquent` class so that my model has all of the awesome Eloquent functionality. For example:

```
class Product extends \Eloquent {
    //class definition here
}
```

I've been reading through the Laravel framework source code, and I don't understand where this `Eloquent` class actually comes from. I can see there is a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class, which seems to have all of the functionality I would expect from the `Eloquent` class that I'm extending, but I'm confused how the inheritance is actually working since I'm extending `Eloquent` , not `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the contents of the file "config/app.php", you will find an "aliases" key towards the bottom of the file. That is what is doing all the magic under the hood. Laravel allows you to alias classes and you can add yours too to the "config/app.php" file so that you do not have to use long, fully qualified names in your code everywhere.

As you can see, the actual class that you are extending is "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model" which is aliased to "Eloquent" hence you only need to extend "Eloquent".

Comment: How does this aliasing work though? If I extend `Eloquent`, how does PHP not throw an error that the class Eloquent wasn't found? I'm trying to find the code that makes that happen.

Comment: I am sure there is a lot happening inside the framework but here is an starting point.

Looking in the file at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;

Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);
 
AliasLoader::getInstance($app['config']['app.aliases'])->register();`

Comment: Thanks. In this array in `config/app.php` I also see an entry for `'SoftDeletingTrait' => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait'`. If this is present, why do I need to include this line at the top of every model using a soft deleting trait? `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;`. Shouldn't I just be able to `use SoftDeletingTrait;` within the model without importing the namespace?

Comment: Have you tried using only `use SoftDeletingTrait` ? I think that should work too and you will not need a fully qualified name.

Comment: At its core, class aliasing uses the php function `class_alias()` to work.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman you're right I didn't need the fully qualified name. I guess this is just left over in the Laravel docs from an older version or something.